# Accessing HDFS files of multiple Kerberos users in the same Spark Job

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs, kerberos

We are running Spark on Kubernetes accessing a Kerberized HDFS cluster. We can access data from individual users by using HDFS Delegation Tokens and from service accounts by using service keytabs.

However, we would like to read/write data **from multiple HDFS accounts in the same** Spark job. In particular:

- Read from a user account, process the data and then save the result to a directory belonging to the service account as an intermediate step of the job (for caching/sharing among users).
- Read from a user account and from a service account in the same job.

All the documentation I was able to find so far covers only the scenario of a single kerberos user per Spark job.

Is it at all possible to use multiple kerberos credentials in a single Spark Job? That is, when reading from `hdfs://mycluster/user/a` use credentials of user A, and when reading from `hdfs://mycluster/user/b` use credentials of user B? We are launching Spark programmatically, as part of a larger Scala program.

We are able to access multiple user accounts from a Java program by using the Hadoop HDFS API directly, doing something like this:

```scala
val ugi1 = UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytabAndReturnUGI(user1, keytab1)
val ugi2 = UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytabAndReturnUGI(user2, keytab2)
val fs1 = ugi1.doAs(new PrivilegedAction[Unit] {
 override def run(): Unit = {
   FileSystem.get(...)
 }
})
val fs2 = ugi2.doAs(new PrivilegedAction[Unit] {
  override def run(): Unit = {
    FileSystem.get(...)
  }
})
// Code using fs1 and fs2
```

We would like to do something similar from a Spark job (running on a Kubernetes cluster). Is this possible? If so, how could we do it?

Comment: That's puzzling. Why don't you just give **permissions** to the service account to access user files, like the rest of the planet _(on HDFS and on any other filesystem)_??

Comment: Recommended reading: all about ACLs (the POSIX standard + the HDFS implementation), especially inheritance.

Comment: We wish we could give more permissions to the service account, but we are not the administrators of the HDFS cluster, so we cannot do it ourselves. We would like to find a way of making this work without having to ask for more permissions, which can take a long time and be somewhat challenging. If it is not possible without modifying Spark, then that is also useful information.

Comment: I guess the users can change the permissions on their own files and directories... a single `hdfs dfs -setfacl` command could give read (or write) permissions to the service account on a whole subtree, incl. files not created yet. On the other hand the service account would also have to grant permissions on the fioles it creates inside user directories.

Comment: Caveat: there was a stupid bug in Hadoop 2 about ACL inheritance. Hopefully you have Hadoop 3.x

Comment: Yes, we are on Hadoop 3.3.0. I had a look at using ACLs, sounded promising, but I quickly found out that the cluster has ACL support disabled (flag `dfs.namenode.acls.enabled` in the Namenode, defaults to false), so that is also not an option, unfortunately.

Comment: So... Kerberos auth but no access control of any kind (no ACL, promiscuous use of keytabs). What's the point? In any serious company, either the CSO would howl at your Admins (and possibly fire a couple to make an example) for their lack of security measures; or the Business Lines would howl at your Admins because the Hadoop cluster is cumbersome to use for no good reason and the inefficiencies cost them time and money that they want to spend elsewhere. Sigh.